# Extract specific cells from multiple closed workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have 500+ spreadsheets that I need to extract 5 rows from each one. They're all saved in the same folder. I just need to be able to create a code that runs through each file in the specified directory, extracts the first 5 rows of each file (only one worksheet per file), and paste the results all in one summarized worksheet.

This is the code I have so far (doesn't work as intended):

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim mainBook As Workbook
Set mainBook = ActiveWorkbook

Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fle As Scripting.File
Dim book As Workbook
For Each fle In fso.GetFolder("C:\dir").Files


    Set book = Workbooks.Open(fle.Path)
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    For Each wks In book.Worksheets

            wks.Range("A5:A10").Copy mainBook.Worksheets(1) 'copies to the  start of the main workbook

    Next
    book.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: "doesn't work as intended" - what's the problem?

Comment: `wks.Range("A5:A10").Copy mainBook.Worksheets(1)`, you need to actually paste to a range, try `mainBook.Worksheets(1).cells(mainBook.Worksheets(1).rows.count,"A").end(xlup).offset(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wks.Range("A5:A10").Copy mainBook.Worksheets(1)`, you need to actually paste to a range, try

```
 wks.Range("A5:A10").Copy mainBook.Worksheets(1).cells(mainBook.Worksheets(1).rows.count,"A").end(xlup).offset(1)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you.